# how can i decrease the voltage of an AC-DC adapter without decreasing current (mAmpire)

Tags: voltage, current, adapter

i have an AC-DC adapter with 5volt 350mA (actually an old cellphone charger). i need to decrease it's voltage to 3volt. i tried adding a resistor in series & it worked, but it also decreased the output current very much. how can i decrease the voltage of without decreasing the current (mA)?

Comment: [Voltage regulators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_regulator)?!!

Answer (score 1):

Use a voltage regulator. The LM7803 will regulate a 5V source down into a 3V one. Using resistors isn't the greatest option as the voltage actually used by your load/device will change with the current drawn by the load/device.

Additionally, the 350mA referenced on the adapter is the maximum rated current, not what will automatically come out.

What application do you need a specific voltage and current for?

Comment: Most would refer to the LM7803 and similar a linear voltage regulator, rather than a DC-DC converter which in practical usage typically implies something a bit more sophisticated such as a switching regulator.

Comment: You're right, I was just using the blanket categories from element14 which considers regulators a subset of DC-DC converters.

Answer (score 0):

Connect three forward biased diodes (e.g. 2N4001) in series to the output to drop the voltage with approximately 2V (3*0.65V).

Another (better) idea - open the adaptor and replace the zener.. I suppose there is such an element inside... I also suppose this is an analog AC-DC converter...